# Remove sub array of object from main array in JavaScript with reference to object value in ie9

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, filter

I need to remove set of item from main array. I have a pick list, when i select and add item from this add to another array and remove from main array.

```js
var mainArray = [
  {
    "name": "abcd"
  },
  {
    "name": "cdf"
  },
  {
    "name": "vdf"
  },
  {
    "name": "ajj"
  },
  {
    "name": "asdf"
  },
  {
    "name": "utyt"
  },
  {
    "name": "adada"
  }
];
var subArray = [
{
    "name": "utyt"
  },
  {
    "name": "adada"
  }
];
  //need main array with out subarray
```

Also I use underscore js. Please help me out

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: mainarray = mainarray.filter(function (item) {
                return subarray.indexOf(item) < 0;
            });
but it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need *underscore* for that, just use *array.prototype.filter* :

```js
var mainArray = [
  {
    "name": "abcd"
  },
  {
    "name": "cdf"
  },
  {
    "name": "vdf"
  },
  {
    "name": "ajj"
  },
  {
    "name": "asdf"
  },
  {
    "name": "utyt"
  },
  {
    "name": "adada"
  }
];
var subArray = [{
    "name": "utyt"
  },
  {
    "name": "adada"
  }];
  
 mainArray = mainArray.filter(function(e) { 
     return !subArray.some(function(s) { 
         return s.name === e.name; 
     });
 });
 console.log(mainArray);
```

Comment: Hi This will not work in ie. Could you please share some thing else

Comment: In ie it show syntax error

Comment: Don'use arrow function

Comment: Updated! arrow function will not work in ie

Comment: get an error  "Object doesn't support property or method 'find'" in ie

Comment: because your 'subArray' is not an array but an object. Ensure it's an array

Comment: so what we need to do?

Comment: Show how your subArray looks like. You can update your question

Comment: [{
    "name": "utyt"
  },
  {
    "name": "adada"
  }]; exactly look like above

Comment: Its array of object

Comment: It seems array.find doesn't works in IE9 so I updated to use array.some

Comment: yes its working thanks :)